# JSONP API Callback not defined

Tags: jsonp

I'm trying to get random quotes from this API - http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback.

API documentation at https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/

Error message from the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: mycallback is not defined. How do I get around the problem? My code below. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    function getNewQuote(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback',
            jsonp: 'jsonp',
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
    });
}

    getNewQuote();
    });
```

Comment: the problem is that you are pasting code without understanding it. watch the url you are calling and try to understand what you are asking...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a callback outside of `$(document).ready()`
like this :

```
var mycallback = function (a) {
    console.log(a);
};
```